# Hide axis tick values

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

Is there a way to hide axis tick values in c3js (version 0.1.42)? In one of the graphs, I have categorical axis with long tick values. I want to hide them and show only on mouseover. I have tried the tick culling option (by setting max to 0) mentioned at http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_culling.html but it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this :

Return empty string in the tick format() method as shown below:-

```
axis : {
    x : {
        type : 'categorized',
        tick: {
            format: function (x) { return ''; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the next code you can hide all x axis ticks

```
   .c3-axis-x .tick line {
      display: none;
    }
```

Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/op4hadqt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try css

```
g.tick:hover text {
    fill: #000;
}
g.tick text {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```