# Hide axis tick values under a certain range in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm looking for a way of hiding axis tick values that fall under a certain range of values in D3.js. For example, let's say my y axis shows values from 0 to 100, showing every 20 of them (0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100). Now, how would one hide certain tick values from showing up? So if I want to hide values 60 and 80, the axis will only show 0, 20, 40, 100.

Let me explain why that question arose. I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107405/how-to-cut-y-axis-to-make-the-chart-look-better) before of how to create a broken y axis. The answer I received was to add midpoints in range and domain of y axis, which really works. BUT, when you add midpoints and don't specify tick values explicitly, you get a mess on that midpoints, since all hiding tick values now appear in the same place.

Here's the screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

The way this could be fixed is to hide tick values that fall under a range of values in that midpoint. There is an analogous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908645/hide-axis-tick-values) but in C3.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm the author of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48109117/5768908) in that question you linked. What I don't quite like in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112740/5768908) is that it's not really *dynamic*. How are you going to calculate `value1` and `value2`?

The approach I'd like to suggest, which is truly dynamic, is using `scale.invert` to get the ticks, simply using the range.

Let's see it. Here is a simple *broken* axis, with the ticks piling up:

```js
var w = 560,
  h = 100;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w + 40)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 20, 800, 1000])
  .range([0, w / 2, w / 2, w]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

What I'm gonna do is simply populating an array based on the range. For instance, getting the values at every 10% of the range, from 0% to 100%:

```
var tickValuesArray = d3.range(11).map(function(d) {
  return ~~scale.invert(w * (d / 10))
});
```

Then, I use it to set the `tickValues`:

```js
var w = 560,
  h = 100;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w + 40)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 20, 800, 1000])
  .range([0, w / 2 , w / 2, w]);
var tickValuesArray = d3.range(11).map(function(d) {
  return ~~scale.invert(w * (d / 10))
});
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale).tickValues(tickValuesArray)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Gerardo! It's indeed a good solution. In my case it's not hard to calculate value1 and value2 dynamically, since one of them is a maximum value of lower bar and second is a minimum value of higher bar.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution from one of the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669239/remove-end-ticks-from-d3-js-axis).

There's a way to remove unnecessary tick values:

```
g.selectAll(".tick")
.each(function (d, i) {
    if ( d > value1 && d < value2 ) {
        this.remove();
    }
});
```